# Get touch position while dragging

Tags: android, drag-and-drop, touch

I have some views which I like to drag around. The views are within 
a LinearLayout, which itself is within a scrollview.

I want to get the position of the current finger (touch), to 
make a smooth scroll on my scrollview, depending of the 
height of the current drag.

I start my draggin after a long click with the 
View build-in listener startDrag

```
view.startDrag(null, shadowBuilder, view, 0);
```

I am also able to get the relativ position of the drag 
on the view that is currently hovered by

```
view.setOnDragListener(new OnDragListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onDrag(View v, DragEvent event) {
            //get event positions
        }
    });
```

But this only works for the view where the drag shadow is currently on 
and DragEvent only provides relative positions, not raw positions.

**What I need is the position of the finger, while the drag happens.** Unfortunately all onTouchEvents get consumed while dragging.

Does anybody know how I get this to work?

*Ps: One way that works (kind of) which I currently use, is to calculate the 
position of the touch via the dragEvent.relativePosition in combination
with the view position. But isn't there a better way to go?*

Comment: Welcome to designing your own custom gesture.  I would look around at how people do gestures. This is an example of a fling http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4139288/android-how-to-handle-right-to-left-swipe-gestures   Or yes you could do the Ps: but if you are dragging something that is a few levels deep in a layout you will need to do a little calculation to get the touch position

Answer (score 18, accepted):

OK, since there seems not to be an easier answer, I will provide my own relativly easy solution for further readers, with no need of gesture detection.

At first you need the view that receives the drag event and at second the
drag event ifself (or at least the x and y coordinates).
With fetching of the view position and some simple addition you get the
raw touch position.

This method is tested with the *show pointer position* developer options
to provide the correct data.

The method for the calculation looks like this:

```
/**
 * @param item  the view that received the drag event
 * @param event the event from {@link android.view.View.OnDragListener#onDrag(View, DragEvent)}
 * @return the coordinates of the touch on x and y axis relative to the screen
 */
public static Point getTouchPositionFromDragEvent(View item, DragEvent event) {
    Rect rItem = new Rect();
    item.getGlobalVisibleRect(rItem);
    return new Point(rItem.left + Math.round(event.getX()), rItem.top + Math.round(event.getY()));
}
```

Call this method inside of your onDragListener implementation:

```
@Override
public boolean onDrag(View v, DragEvent event) {
    switch (event.getAction()) {
        case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_STARTED:
            //etc etc. do some stuff with the drag event
            break;
        case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_LOCATION:
            Point touchPosition = getTouchPositionFromDragEvent(v, event);
            //do something with the position (a scroll i.e);
            break;
         default: 
   }
   return true;
}
```

Addtional:
If you want to determinate if the touch is inside of a specific view, you can
do something like this:

```
 public static boolean isTouchInsideOfView(View view, Point touchPosition) {
    Rect rScroll = new Rect();
    view.getGlobalVisibleRect(rScroll);
    return isTouchInsideOfRect(touchPosition, rScroll);
}

public static boolean isTouchInsideOfRect(Point touchPosition, Rect rScroll) {
    return touchPosition.x > rScroll.left && touchPosition.x < rScroll.right //within x axis / width
            && touchPosition.y > rScroll.top && touchPosition.y < rScroll.bottom; //withing y axis / height
}
```

It is also possible to implement a smooth scroll on a ListView based on this solution.
So that the user can drag an item out of a list, and scroll the list via dragging the item either to the top or bottom of the list view.

Cheers.

Comment: hi, will you please proper implementation flow i am stuck in this type issue, if its demo then it will be good.